# Comparison of two lists in python

Tags: python, list, postgresql

I have a list, which contains information about the class number and the keywords. I will call it 'class-list':

```
    [(0, ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4']), (1, ['word5', 'word6', 'word7', 'word8']), (2, ['word1', 'word9', 'word3', 'word7'])
```

And I have a postgres database, where every entry has a list of words, let's say a 'db-list'.

```
    ['word1', 'word2', 'word10', 'word7', 'word3']
```

The idea is to assign the class to the data in the database based on the 'class-list'. If 'db-list' contains the word1 and the word2 then the class '0' will be assigned to this description.
I don't know how to write the condition "if two elements of the 'db-list' (of k) == two elements of the 'class-list'". Any help is highly appreciated!

```
    cur.execute("SELECT * From table")
    dbrows = cur.fetchall()
    for k in dbrows:
        if two elements of the 'db-list' (of k) == two elements of the 'class-list':
            sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (class);"""
            cur.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create sets from both keyword lists and count elements in the intersection subset. Example:

```
dblist = [(0, ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4']), (1, ['word5', 'word6', 'word7', 'word8']), (2, ['word1', 'word9', 'word3', 'word7'])]
dbrow = ['word1', 'word2', 'word10', 'word7', 'word3']

for class_idx, kwords in dblist:
    if len(set(dbrow) & set(kwords)) == 2:
        print kwords  # or do whatever you need
```